# Tar exit code 0 despite error "Cannot open: No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, tar, exit-code, ubuntu-16.04

I'm creating an archive from within a script and would like to perform some actions if this fails for whatever reason.

The code to check the error case looks something like this:

```
if ! sudo tar -zcf "/not/existing/dest.tar.gz" "/existing/archive/src/"; then
    echo "Tar failed"
fi
echo "Tar exited with error code $?"
```

Which results in the following output:

```
tar (child): /not/existing/dest.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Tar exited with error code 0
```

Why is tar exiting with code 0, even though it obviously fails?

Some more infos:

**OS:** Ubuntu 16.04
**tar --version:** tar (GNU tar) 1.28
**sudo --version:** version 1.8.16

Comment: @Cyrus If it's not 0 then it should echo `Tar failed`.

Answer (score 2):

`$?` takes its value from the last command executed.

In your last `echo`, it takes it from the previous `echo`, which is of course executed properly.

```
if ! sudo tar -zcf "/not/existing/dest.tar.gz" "/existing/archive/src/"; then
    echo "Tar failed"                 # if it fails
fi                                    # |  
echo "Tar exited with error code $?"  # |
#                                ^^_____| it comes here
```

Comment: Hm, sounds reasonable at first glance but doesn't completely match up since "Tar failed" is never printed. Therefore the `echo "Tar failed"` command is never executed and the error code is IMHO from `tar` itself... Am I missing something here?

Comment: @suamikim good point. Just to be sure, if you type `sudo tar -zcf "/not/existing/dest.tar.gz" "/existing/archive/src/"` and then `echo $?`, do you get 0 or someething else?

Comment: Yes, `echo $?` directly after the plain `tar` command in the console prints `0`...

Comment: This is quite strange. I just typed `tar adlfajsdfklasj adfjaskd` and got _tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors_; then `echo $?` returned 2. To me, it looks like your `tar` does not consider this as a "proper" error as described in [GNU tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Synopsis.html). Quoting there, I would then say that this is kind of a case on _s. Some errors are recoverable, in which case the failure is delayed until tar has completed all its work_.

Comment: If both, the destination & the source don't exist, I also get the error code 2. Could you try this exact command with an existing source directory? `sudo tar -zcf "/not/existing/fstab.tar.gz" "/etc/fstab"`

Comment: @suamikim sure. It did work without any problem and the return code was 0. The problem is that the server I am ssh'ing to does not allow me to `sudo`, so it is not the exact command.

Comment: With that exact command I get 2 on a system with sudo 1.8.10p3, and 141 on a system with sudo 1.8.9p5. GNU tar 1.27.1 on both.

Comment: One more thing: `tar` explicitly prints `Error is not recoverable: exiting now` on `stderr` (see my initial post), therefore the `...Some errors are recoverable...` stuff from GNU tar is imho not the case...

Comment: @suamikim true, good point. Could you update your question showing your `tar --version` and `sudo --version`. Hints by _that other guy_ are interesting.